# How to search another site using PHP

Tags: php, joomla

A client wants his site to link to another site for the purpose of searching that site's database.  What's the best way to do this using PHP and/or Joomla?

Comment: Would be useful to know the purpose/type of search required and whether or not the second site offers an API for searching

Comment: The purpose of the search is to locate car parts from a second site, using the second site's search functionality.  To my knowledge, the owner's of the second site don't provide an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that site have the values you are interested in show up on their front-end, because then all you would need to do is write a site-scraper using PHP (optionally using cURL). You'd programmatically go to their site, perform search functions, and return what you get.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would need to pass in user search criteria.

Comment: That's fine, you can do that with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already comfortable with Joomla you could just make a 'wrapper' page and show the other site inside the iframe that the wrapper gives you. A tiny bit crude but very quick and easy to do.

Joomla will make a wrapper page for you with no programming through your menu interface in the admin.